# How to use ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat?

Tags: android, view, android-support-library

I'm trying to make an animation in my app available in older android version and I'm using ViewPropertyAnimator by calling view.animate().

But how can I get a [ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.html) of the view?

Answer (score 2):

Use `ViewCompat`.

```
    ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat animator = ViewCompat.animate(view);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
This works in code, but nothing happens when I'm starting the animator on an older api level. Do you know, why this could be so?